# How to group similar news text / article in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp, similarity

**I have a pandas dataframe of news article. Suppose**

| id | news title | keywords | publcation date | content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Congress Wants to Beef Up Army Effort to Develop Counter-Drone Weapons | USA,Congress,Drone,Army | 2020-12-10 | SOME NEWS CONTENT |
| 2 | Israel conflict: The range and scale of Hamas' weapons ... | Israel,Hamas,Conflict | 2020-12-10 | NEWS CONTENT |
| 3 | US Air Force progresses testing of anti-drone laser weapons | USA,Air Force,Weapon,Dron | 2020-10-10 | NEWS CONTENT |
| 4 | Hamas fighters display weapons in Gaza after truce with Israel | Hamas,Gaza,Israel,Weapon,Truce | 2020-11-10 | NEWS CONTENT |

Now 
**HOW TO GROUP SIMILAR DATA BASED ON NEWS CONTENT AND SORT BY PUBLICATION DATE**
*Note:The content may be summary of the news*
So that it displays as:

---

*Group1*

| id | news title | keywords | publcation date | content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | US Air Force progresses testing of anti-drone laser weapons | USA,Air Force,Weapon,Dron | 2020-10-10 | NEWS CONTENT |
| 1 | Congress Wants to Beef Up Army Effort to Develop Counter-Drone Weapons | USA,Congress,Drone,Army | 2020-12-10 | SOME NEWS CONTENT |

---

*Group2*

| id | news title | keywords | publcation date | content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Hamas fighters display weapons in Gaza after truce with Israel | Hamas,Gaza,Israel,Weapon,Truce | 2020-11-10 | NEWS CONTENT |
| 2 | Israel conflict: The range and scale of Hamas' weapons ... | Israel,Hamas,Conflict | 2020-12-10 | NEWS CONTENT |

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit complicated, I choose the easy way for the similarity, but you can change the function as you wish.

1. you can also use https://pypi.org/project/pyjarowinkler/ for the is_similar function instead of the "set" I did. *the function can be much more complicated than the one I did
2. I used two applies the first one is to fit the "grps". it will work without the first one but it will be more accurate at the second time
3. you can also change the range(3,-1,-1) to a higher number for the accuracy

   ```
    def is_similar(txt1,txt2,level=0):
        return len(set(txt1) & set(txt2))>level

    grps={}
    def get_grp_id(row):
        row_words = row['keywords'].split(',')
        if len(grps.keys())==0:
            grps[1]=set(row_words)
            return 1
        else:
            for level in range(3,-1,-1):
                for grp in grps:
                    if is_similar(grps[grp],row_words,level):
                        grps[grp]= grps[grp] | set(row_words)
                        return grp

            grp +=1
            grps[grp]=set(row_words)
            return grp


    df.apply(get_grp_id,axis=1)
    df['grp'] = df.apply(get_grp_id,axis=1)
    df = df.sort_values(['grp','publcation date'])
   ```

this is the output
[image]

if you want to split it into separate df let me know

Comment: Can you please explain how we are grouping it and if I have to approach grouping based on similarity of news content i.e similarity score calculated with 3rd party library . How would I go about grouping it.

Comment: Can you please explain how we are grouping it and if I have to approach grouping based on similarity of news content i.e similarity score calculated with 3rd party library . How would I go about grouping it. Suppose i have a list of similarities for every combination of data i.e for 40 rows i.e 780 combinations ..having pairwise similarity how would I group it.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by grouping it,
my method is to run on the keywords and as higher the level in similarity function as the more likely it will be similar.
if you can show the input and the expected output it will be easier